# DialogFragment animation of layout and "Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!" error

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment which has some animations of some of the layouts inside its view.
When I dismiss the dialog, I want to perform an animation and when the animation has ended, perform the dismiss operation.

Step1:
Call the fragment from my activity:

```
myDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
```

Step 2:
After the user had completed the job with the dialog, he presses a button. That button calls an animation and after that I want the dialog to disappear:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

        layMain = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.layMain);

        TextView btnCancel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_to_bottom);
                    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    layMain.startAnimation(anim);
                }
            });
.....
```

When the animations ends, the dialog gets dismissed but I get this error on logcat

> E/ViewRootImpl(25507): Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!
>   E/ViewRootImpl(25507):   window=android.view.ViewRootImpl@427348e0,
>   title=com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity

How can I prevent this ?

Later edit: if I am using it without any animation, everything works fine and no error is shown on logcat. So I suppose it has to do something with the animation.

The animation I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

  <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="80%p" />

</set>
```

Comment: that means that your dialog has been not disappeared??

Comment: The dialog disappears as the normal expectation. So everything behaves normal, except that error message which.. can't mean something good.

Comment: This is because you have pass the getSupportFragmentManager() as a context object...so instead of it you have pass getActivity()....

Comment: I don't understand your answer, could you please elaborate a bit ? The thing is, if I am using it without an animation, dismiss does not generate the error. So it has to be something with the animation.

Comment: What do you do in that animation(maybe stepping outside of the dialog)? You can always use one of the dialog views to `post()` a `Runnable` on it with the `dismiss()` call.

Comment: In the animation I am taking the root layout of the dialog view and slide it to the bottom.

Comment: Did you tried, like I said in the above comment, to post() a `Runnable` with the dismiss() call on one of the dialog views(like btnCancel)?

Comment: You mean something like `handler.postDelayed()` ?

Comment: No, I was referring more to `btnCancel.post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {dismiss();}});` in the `animationEnd` callback.

Comment: Can you post your animation file and your layout file. I am trying to recreate this but I am not getting the exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only solution that works so far, without throwing an error is this:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dismiss();
        }
    }, 10);
```

}

I am open to any other sugestions

Comment: You don't need the 10 ms delay. You can simply use the `post()` method.

Comment: This is very late. But today in 2020, using @ItaiHanski solution works. In my case, I am closing the dialog with animation. Overriding the dismiss() method, I put my super.dismiss() method in the OnAnimationEnd(), wrapped by Handler().post { }, as suggested above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have pass fragment context as a getSupportFragmentManager().
So you have to change it:

```
myDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
```

Comment: `void android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)`  requires fragment manager not activity.

Comment: I need to use Support fragment manager as my apps needs to be compatible starting from android 2.2

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any such issues:

```
public class MyDIalog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Button b = new Button(getActivity());
        final Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        d.setContentView(b);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                b.animate().rotationYBy(180).setDuration(500).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                        dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return d;
    }

}
```

works fine with:

```
new MyDIalog().show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");
```

Any ways, you can schedule the `dismiss()` call a bit later by using:

```
 @Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      dismiss();
    }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately is not working. As I said, if I don't use animations, the error does not occur. The difference from your code is that I am using onCreateView and getSupportFragmentManger. Maybe there is a bug in support library?

Comment: @Alin Maybe, I tested on emulator with ICS platform, it worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
@Override 
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            dismiss(); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

here, the advantage is, you don't define your own time, this way it may help to keep everything else simple, as a user can surprise you even within a short duration if dialog kept without dismissing after the animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's too late to answer your question but the only way to get rid of this error is to post the dialogue removal code in a view's post method in your onAnimationEnd().
for example:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {  
    @Override  
    public void run() {  
        windowManager.removeView(layout);
    } 
});
```